# Java and SOAP data client request as UTC time and save as EST time

Tags: java, soap

I have a soap client request that I need to convert the date response into EST time.

On my screen, I selected: 11:45am and I want to save 11:45 am in the database.

But the SOAP request comes in as:

2012-11-24T16:45:00.000Z

In java code, the date prints as:

Sat Nov 24 11:45:00 EST 2012
...

Yet we make another web-service call which eventually saves to the database (SQL Server):
2012-11-24 16:45

```
Calendar incomingWebServiceCalendarObject = fromWebService.getDateTime()

Calendar outgoingWebServiceCalendarObject = incomingWebServiceCalendarObject;
webServiceBean.setDateTime(outgoingWebServiceCalendarObject);
```

...
How can I save as 2012-11-24 11:45?

Also, here is the gregorian calendar:

java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1353775500000,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="America/New_York",offset=-18000000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=235,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=America/New_York,offset=-18000000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=3,startMonth=2,startDay=8,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=7200000,startTimeMode=0,endMode=3,endMonth=10,endDay=1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=7200000,endTimeMode=0]],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2012,MONTH=10,WEEK_OF_YEAR=47,WEEK_OF_MONTH=4,DAY_OF_MONTH=24,DAY_OF_YEAR=329,DAY_OF_WEEK=7,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=4,AM_PM=0,HOUR=11,HOUR_OF_DAY=11,MINUTE=45,SECOND=0,MILLISECOND=0,ZONE_OFFSET=-18000000,DST_OFFSET=0]

...

I did the following and this appears to work, is this a proper approach, what is the code trying to accomplish based on my requirement?

```
final long offset = this.secondaryScheduleTime.getTimeInMillis() + TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST").getRawOffset();
final Date estTime = new Date(offset);
final Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
c2.setTime(estTime);
```

Comment: i seriously doubt you want to store the data in your database in the local timezone unless you are _also_ storing the timezone with the data.  using an implicit local timezone for storage is a headache waiting to happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your initial SOAP request is coming in as UTC (`.000Z` is your timezone information), after which your Calendar object converts it to Eastern time  `,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="America/New_York"...` for display and then you are persisting the original SOAP information to your database.

What you don't show is *how* you are persisting your database and with *which* timestamp.

I can think of only 2 situations you have going on:

1. Your database is in UTC only and no timezone information is saved. This means that each call to/from your DB is always UTC and timezones are left up to your code.
2. Your database saves timezone info via the Timestamp datatype, but you are sending the UTC information from your SOAP request to your database, not your local Calendar object.

I think the solution you provided satisfies #2 on the list above, but again, without seeing any other details I think it will be hard to determine for sure.

I would suggest dropping some break points and stepping through your code to see exactly when/where your date objects are being created, and with what information.

Comment: I corrected my post. We actually take the "Calendar" object from one web-service call and feed that to another web-service.  At the second web-service that is where we actually save to a sql server database.  I don't have access to that web-service code that is doing the saving (C#).

Comment: Unless the remote SQL Server setup has your schema set to use datetimeoffset as the datatype for your dates, all dates are stored in UTC. This would be a real good reason why the database is always showing UTC. See here for more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630289.aspx

Comment: However, the code you posted shows that scenario #2 is actually occurring: `Calendar outgoingWebServiceCalendarObject = incomingWebServiceCalendarObject;` which should be `Calendar outgoingWebServiceCalendarObject = c2;`

Comment: You are right, I will try the solution.  Is that an OK approach?

Comment: Depends - if having local time being reflected as UTC is the database works for all business needs now and in the future, then go nuts - however I strongly caution against mixing UTC with local time. If a point comes where you require the UTC value, it will be a nightmare to sort out. Consider this: You have an service order system that services technicians worldwide, if they require a create date for the service order it will be reflected in EST. Say they are in Dubai (+4 UTC) - your DB time is off by -8/-9 (depending on DST) and needs to be incremented accordingly, vs getting localization.

Comment: If you are able to keep it as UTC, then your code will need to only consider the local computers regional settings in order to sort out your correct time zone differences, ensuring that the end users time is always the local time, regardless of where in the world they are.